# How can I ask a question which hasn't been answered before without it being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, asking-questions, question-quality

So, I've asked a simple question about a topic which hasn't been asked before. I've researched quite a bit and said I couldn't find any satisfying answers and even included some links to the articles.

In the first few minutes I received some great answers and I'm grateful for the experts on this site who took the time to answer. Those answers were also upvoted quite a bit. So I'm coming back to work today and I see my reputation is 12 lower than yesterday. I'm a newbie so all the features I unlocked by being a genuine guy and helping people were suddenly locked again.

What I find agonizing is that I have received quite a bit of downvotes even for a well researched, properly formatted, grammatically correct (at least to the best of my ability) and genuine question.

I have checked the link which provides information on how to ask a good question. I'm even running a risk on getting banned from asking questions which I certainly don't want to happen because I'm an apprentice and don't have a lot of coding experience.

Should I take this 'advice' seriously and refrain from asking for help even when I am not able to answer my own question with a reasonable amount of effort?

Comment: It is more a conceptual question then a practical programming question. Those might work better on software engineering.se. Only linking to articles you have read is not enough for these conceptual questions. You need to explain what you don't understand and/or what your hypothesis is based on what you have read. Without that the question is not extremely useful. Not sure if the too broad close votes are correct there but those are often casted when users expect they have to explain a concept from the ground up in an answer.

Comment: If you are following the guidelines, don't sweat much about the downvotes. They are there to help you improve, take them positively and dont get demotivated. Your question _What is a Concrete Class in C#_ can attract downvotes based on just the post title itself. Your other question is much better w.r.t the post quality expected by SO.

Comment: The problem exists that your question about concrete classes doesn't seem very well researched. And answering it would require copying one of the answers in the question you linked: you are asking about basic OOP concepcts and the answer is going to be the same in any language.

Comment: Side note: to my knowledge C# has classes, abstract classes and sealed classed but no formal definition for "concrete classes"... (Indeed it exists as general programming concept - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_Concrete ... With such questions it is good idea to refer to actual language specification first and to random posts on internet second,

Comment: IMO, the question could have been closed as a dupe to the question you are linking, with a comment saying "yes, these concepts are the same in both languages"

Comment: Concrete class is define by its opposition to Abstract class. So looking for concrete class definition will show you the definition of abstract and interface. This is a duplicate as Abstract and/vs Interface is a common question. During your reseach you must have read that Concrete were nothing more than something that is not Abstract. But without one saying it directly yo you you didn't compute this information and was looking for something else. The more you read, the more you were looking for a detail. You have the answer in your question. we just read it to you.

Comment: @DragandDrop Right, I processed this now it's really just a stupid question and I understand why it's been downvoted.

Comment: @user10511180, yep we all have those dumb question from time to time. It doesnt mean you r dumb. Sometime we just need the "click". I only talked about your question. For the downvote, I must say that I feel no urge to dw your question, it's not bad nor good. In fact I commented your question before the dw.

Comment: Something worth bearing in mind. You can delete any of your questions and answers that have net negative rep score, and your rep should go back up. As far as I know the only time you risk a potential penalty is if you delete a question that has answers. Do this too often, and the site penalises you by limiting the questions you can ask. I believe the rationale is that if you ask a bad question and delete it after people have provided answers: the delete is being inconsiderate of those who answered.

Comment: @Watcher - Thats not a very good suggestion, deleted questions also count towards a question ban so you should only be deleting content when you believe it no longer holds value.

Comment: Seems like the actual answer to your question is now in these comments!  I find it unfortunate that the question was deleted.

Comment: User disappeared off SOF seems ..

Comment: This post is kind of a dead link resource for <10k users with the post deleted, I'm trying to interpret @rene's suggestion but it's hard to visualize without the original post. Archive.org is no help, can I get a screenshot, preferably with answers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I presume you're talking about your [concrete class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52855592/1324033) question...

The main problem I see here is that you don't *explain* why those duplicates aren't any good, so that makes it unclear what answer you're looking for when what might be seen as the right answer didn't solve your issue.

Bad

> The answers here are not understandable explained either

Good (Better)

> The answers here are not understandable explained either because they talk about X but I don't see how X addresses Y.

Other than that, you could add some additional formatting since one long paragraph isn't very nice to look at. It's not the worst question I've seen, so I probably wouldn't downvote it, but I wouldn't be upvoting it either.

Comment: _"The answers here are not understandable explained either"_ What?

Comment: @canon - that was taken directly from the OP's question, the important part was that the OP needed to add an explanation but I agree that could be written better

Comment: "It's not the worst question I've seen, so I probably wouldn't downvote it..." You would only downvote a question if it's worse than all others you've seen before? =)